# How can I keep a local svn-git repo in sync with .svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am working on a project that uses SVN as repository which I use in combination with the Netbeans SVN plugin. I found Netbeans SVN diff lacking on showing several diffs below each other and therefore wanted to use `git-svn` for being able to use `git gui`.

The problem is now keeping both repositories in sync. My current workflow is:

- Updating (with no local changes):

  ```
  svn up
  git stash -u # include new files too
  git svn rebase
  git stash drop
  ```
- Comitting:

  ```
  git commit
  git commit ...
  git svn dcommit
  ```

These base cases do work, but it does not work nicely if I have local unstaged/uncomitted changes.

What is a better way to keep the local git-svn and .svn in sync?

Comment: This [Git and Subversion chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) of the Pro Git book may help.

Comment: @Mightymuke Nope, it does not give me new insights or solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround that works pretty well. The idea is to keep files updated using subversion and have git only update its history without touching any files in the working tree. `git svn` created a special `git-svn` branch which contains the latest subversion code once fetched.

The commands to update your files, followed by a git repo history update:

```
svn up
git svn fetch
git reset --mixed git-svn
```

The last `git reset --mixed` command is necessary to ensure that git knows that your files are from the last SVN revision. Note that this command will reset any commits you made with `git commit` (remove commit messages, not the changes). As a solution for that, commit via `svn commit` and fetch your history as shown above.

`git reset --mixed git-svn` somehow unables you to commit to use `dcommit`. After running `git reset --mixed git-svn`, follow the following sequence to commit using git:

```
git stash
git svn rebase
git stash pop
git commit ...
git svn dcommit
```